# Cannot Connect To MySQL - Cannot Find Mysql.sock Phpmyadmin Error #2002

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have been working on a mysql database that I set up with phpmyadmin... I copied the database on my server to a different directory on my mac server so a website I am developing can access it... When I changed the MySQL setting in Server Admin to the new directory location, it could not connect to the database anymore, after I saved and restarted the service.  I have rebooted the server as well.

I did not alter any files as I copied them to the directory of my website.

Seeing as that did not work, I put the setting back to the default directory of /var/mysql , then saved & restarted the service.

In the Overview of Server Admin, it states: MySql Service is: Shutting Down.  I have tried: clicking start MySQL at the bottom (the program is responding), restarting the service, removed and added the service, and changed the permissions of the /var/mysql folder.

When I try to access mysql through phpmyadmin in a web browser, I get: #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server.

I figure the MySQL server did not start and is having a problem doing so.  From my research on the web I need to verify that mysql.sock exists in the /var/mysql dir.... which it does not.  I did a search of my mac and could not find it.  I do not wish to reinstall this as I shouldn't have to.

In terminal, I have tried this:
mysqladmin restart
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysql is running and that the socket: '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!

Any Ideas??  Everything is up to date as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I just reinstalled mySQL package on that server, and didn't touch phpmyadmin and it worked.  Thank you for the input though

Comment: Err, @GottliebNotschnabel, "Reinstalled it", *is* an answer.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is not running.

Try one of these from the command prompt:

- To **start** mysql server:

  ```
  /etc/init.d/mysqld start
  ```
- To **stop** mysql server:

  ```
  /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
  ```
- To **restart** mysql server:

  ```
  /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
  ```

Also try:

```
service mysqld restart
```

You will need to tell MySQL to start automatically if it's always not started.

Failing that - my bet would be to re-install MySQL and MAC's startup/pref thing.

Comment: The Directory etc/init.d/ doesn't exist.

Comment: [It will most probably be `launchd`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735320/osx-s-etc-init-d-equivalent)