# osx' s /etc/init.d equivalent?

Tags: linux, macos

I am installing gitlab on a mac but this latter is mainly designed for linux os. Following the doc, I have to run this command

```
curl --output /etc/init.d/gitlab https://raw.github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/master/init.d/gitlab
```

What is the mac equivalent of the /etc/init.d folder (I know about the `launchd` command but I am looking for the mac's equivalent /etc/init.d folder) ?

Comment: I am going to disappoint you: it **is** `launchd`.

Comment: @H2CO3 so the command would be curl --output /launchd/gitlab https://raw.github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/master/init.d/gitlab ?

Comment: @userXXX No, but `launchd` has a nice man page which you can google.

Comment: @user1611830 there is no init.d on OS X. Launchd is the OS X equivalent. You should read the man page.

Comment: @H2CO3, sorry I am quite confused to bother, but should I replace /etc/init.d by /System/Library in the above command ?

Comment: who down voted this question? or why?

Answer (score 30):

AFAIK, `launchd` stores its data primarily in `.plist` files in `/Library/LaunchAgents/` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`, and occasionally in those subdirectories in your home directory. More on those files in [this tutorial](http://nathangrigg.net/2012/07/schedule-jobs-using-launchd/#launchctl) and [this reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html).

For your problem specifically, to set `launchd` up to run gitlab, try converting that `init.d` script to a `.plist` file with the links above.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if you still care about the question or not, but what ryan said is correct.  And to directly answer your question, your curl command is trying to download a startup script and put it into your init.d directory.  You don't have one, as you are on Mac OS X.

What you need to do is pop that init.d somewhere else that is permanent.  Make sure it is chmod +x and test to see if it works manually.  (ie. ./init.d)

If it does, you can create a .plist and pop it into /Library/LaunchDaemons/ that will run your init.d file.    If your init.d file is as simple as just running an executable, then forget the init.d file entirely, and just have the .plist file run the gitlab executable file directly.

Either way, I think that you should mark Ryan's (or mine as well) answer as Accepted, as it will solve your issue.  The only reason I didn't put this as a comment on Ryan's answer is that my explanation was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

For a system with M1, it is stored in `/sbin/launchd`

It is differentiated with the PID 1

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).