# Where is init folder in macs from where I can load my .conf file based jobs

Tags: linux, macos, supervisord

I just migrated from linux, and trying to run one of my solutions in mac, 
at my linux i had a .conf files while was used to change the "run level" and start a supervisor job at the start of machine.

Is there a similar implementation somewhere at the mac as well, if not then what's the alternative.

my .conf based job was used to look like this

```
description "myJob"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec supervisord --nodaemon --configuration <path to my config file>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735320/osx-s-etc-init-d-equivalent

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent on OS X would be a launch daemon -- a property list file in /Library/LaunchDaemons that tells launchd when to launch your program. If I understand what your .conf file does, the equivalent would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>local.myJob</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/path/to/your/script</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Name that local.myJob.plist, put it in /Library/LaunchDaemons, set the owner to root and permissions to 644, and then either reboot or load it with `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.myJob.plist`.

See [man launchd.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) and Apple's developer document ["Creating Launch Daemons and Agents"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)for more info and options. You can also look at the Apple-provided daemons in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons for more examples.