# Removing Saltstack from Mac OSX

Tags: macos, salt-stack

I don't remember how I installed saltstack on my mac, so I tried uninstalling it every way possible. I tried `brew uninstall saltstack`, `pip uninstall salt`. I attempted to see if `salt -h` had anything to say to uninstall it, but it didn't work.

**Update** some system outputs

`➤ pip list | grep salt
➤ whereis salt-call
➤ which salt-call
/opt/salt/bin/salt-call
➤ ls -l /opt/salt
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  45 root  wheel   1.5K 24 Aug 13:07 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel   272B 24 Aug 13:07 include/
drwxr-xr-x  14 root  wheel   476B 24 Aug 13:07 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel   272B 24 Aug 13:07 openssl/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel   102B 24 Aug 13:07 share/`

I'm guessing I installed it from [this link](https://repo.saltstack.com/index.html):

`curl -L https://bootstrap.saltstack.com -o install_salt.sh
sudo sh install_salt.sh -P -M`

but it doesn't say how to uninstall it based on this method. Anyone know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> /opt/salt/bin/salt-call

It looks like you installed it using `.pkg` file: https://repo.saltstack.com/osx/

You can verify by running some commands:

```
❯❯❯❯ pkgutil --pkgs | grep salt
com.saltstack.salt

❯❯❯❯ pkgutil --pkg-info com.saltstack.salt
package-id: com.saltstack.salt
version: 2016.11.3
volume: /
location: /
install-time: 1504874150
```

List installed files:

```
❯❯❯❯ pkgutil --files com.saltstack.salt
Library
Library/LaunchDaemons
Library/LaunchDaemons/com.saltstack.salt.api.plist
Library/LaunchDaemons/com.saltstack.salt.master.plist
Library/LaunchDaemons/com.saltstack.salt.minion.plist
Library/LaunchDaemons/com.saltstack.salt.syndic.plist
etc
etc/salt
etc/salt/master.dist
etc/salt/minion.dist
opt
opt/salt
opt/salt/bin
...
```

Stop services:

```
❯❯❯❯ sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.saltstack.salt.minion.plist
```

Do the same for `api`, `master`, `syndic` if they are running.

**Make sure you're in the root directory:**

```
❯❯❯❯ cd /
```

Remove files first:

```
❯❯❯❯ pkgutil --only-files --files com.saltstack.salt | grep -v opt
Library/LaunchDaemons/com.saltstack.salt.api.plist
Library/LaunchDaemons/com.saltstack.salt.master.plist
Library/LaunchDaemons/com.saltstack.salt.minion.plist
Library/LaunchDaemons/com.saltstack.salt.syndic.plist
etc/salt/master.dist
etc/salt/minion.dist

❯❯❯❯ pkgutil --only-files --files com.saltstack.salt | grep -v opt | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 sudo rm -f
```

then directories:

```
❯❯❯❯ pkgutil --only-dirs --files com.saltstack.salt | grep -v opt
Library
Library/LaunchDaemons
etc
etc/salt

❯❯❯❯ sudo rm -fr etc/salt

❯❯❯❯ sudo rm -fr opt/salt
```

And finally, remove the receipt:

```
❯❯❯❯ sudo pkgutil --forget com.saltstack.salt
Forgot package 'com.saltstack.salt' on '/'.
```

Comment: A couple more things: `sudo rm /etc/paths.d/salt` `find /usr/local/sbin -lname '/opt/salt/*' | xargs sudo rm -v`

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't know exactly how it was installed it is a little difficult to tell how to get rid of it.

The mentioned link points to a script that is [salt-bootstrap](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/salt_bootstrap.html) behind the scene - OSX is not mentioned there as supported, but maybe it works the BSD-way for OSX in this case.

Did you stumbled upon [this page](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/installation/osx.html) - it actually shows multiple ways of installing saltstack on OS X. Maybe you recognize what you've done before.

However in the end salt is just a bunch of python files. What does `pip list` say? Or `whereis salt-call`? This should give you some hints where salt is located.

Comment: I've updated the question with some more info. Seems like that isn't it. I could delete the `/opt/salt` folder but I'm worried there is some init process somewhere I'm missing. Let me know what you think :-)

Comment: hm - I recently installed salt with the bootstrap script on freebsd - it does not put anything in `/opt` - i doubt you used `salt-bootstrap` for install. what does `ls -l /opt/salt` shows up?

Comment: Added to the question :-)

Comment: sry 4 late response - i would just remove the files and check if there is anything there which makes a daemon out of the minion. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735320/osx-s-etc-init-d-equivalent helps?