# cannot connect to phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem , I v never seen it before

```
Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL.
```

after searching for the solution, thought of changing the password
right after changing the password it says password is successfully changed, then I retry to login
it  says:

```
2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

And this is not on my localhost.

please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: Did you google that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449721/cannot-connect-to-mysql-database-phpmyadmin?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735497/cannot-connect-to-mysql-cannot-find-mysql-sock-phpmyadmin-error-2002?rq=1 e t.c.

Comment: atleast show some code

Comment: It's not clear to me if your connection error happens with phpMyAdmin or with another application; please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following things.

1) In mysql server check the user you have created should have privilege for all the hosts.i.e., in your `mysql.user`  table you have to check the following.

```
========================
 user | passwd | host 
=========================

uname | passwd | **%**
```

if the host is `localhost` please change it into '%'.

2) please check the port is opened for mysql in your connecting server by using `telnet` command

It will help you to resolve the problem